# If I save files in iCloud, where are they "really"?

Tags: icloud, macos, filesystem

If I save files to iCloud in apps in Mountain Lion that support such saving, where on my drive can I find these files if I want to run command line utilities on them, edit them in other programs, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're located at `~/Library/Mobile Documents`.

[image]

Each application has its own individual folder under Mobile Documents where its documents and settings are stored.

Comment: not the cleanest looking location (compared to say ~/Dropbox) :/

Answer (score 1):

[image]The folder `~/Library/Mobile Documents` seems to be the magic iCloud folder. In fact, if you open said folder in the Finder, the folder name changes to **iCloud** and it gets a cloud icon rather than a standard folder icon. Pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> will not return you to the `~/Library` folder.